# Как сделать перенаправление на другую локальную страницу при получении JWT-токена?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jwt

Использую авторизацию с помощью JWT токенов, и при проверке логина и пароля токен выдается, но как сделать чтобы после успешного получения токена пользователя перенаправляли на другую страницу?

вот код получения токена:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tokenKey = "accessToken";

    // отпавка запроса к контроллеру AccountController для получения токена
    async function getTokenAsync() {

        // получаем данные формы и фомируем объект для отправки
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("grant_type", "password");
        formData.append("username", document.getElementById("emailLogin").value);
        formData.append("password", document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value);

        // отправляет запрос и получаем ответ
        const response = await fetch("/token", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
            body: formData
        });
        // получаем данные
        const data = await response.json();

        // если запрос прошел нормально
        if (response.ok === true) {

            // сохраняем в хранилище sessionStorage токен доступа
            sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
            console.log(data.access_token);
        }
        else {
            // если произошла ошибка, из errorText получаем текст ошибки
            console.log("Error: ", response.status, data.errorText);
        }
    };
    // отправка запроса к контроллеру ValuesController
    async function getData(url) {
        const token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token  // передача токена в заголовке
            }
        });
        if (response.ok === true) {

            const data = await response.json();
            alert(data)
        }
        else
            console.log("Status: ", response.status);
    };

    // получаем токен
    document.getElementById("submitLogin").addEventListener("click", e => {

        e.preventDefault();
        getTokenAsync();
    });


</script>
```

getData и getDataAsync пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для редиректа используется `location.assign(url)`